# Server check every minute

Tags: ios, sql-server, database, push-notification, push

I am creating an iOS app that lets users store a favored time within the settings that would be added to a database.  I am trying to set up a server that will match the database times to the server times and when it matches, send a push notification. Could use a little guidance as to how to set up the server-side check and how to address potentially having 10,000-100,000 entries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very wide open question, but I would start with putting the time in 24 hour format into an integer column and create a clustered index on that column. Then you can run a query once a minute returning only the records for the current time interval and loop through them to trigger the push notifications.

If you need a more detailed answer you should post a few more details about your problem.